# Why am I getting error in CodeChef Closest Divisor program?

Tags: c++, numbers, c++14, theory, number-theory

I am trying to solve
[Codechef Closest Divisor Problem](https://www.codechef.com/YTPP001/problems/CLODIV)

*I can't figure out why it gives me wrong solution.*

**The problem statement is**

> Given two integers A and B, find the largest number ≤A which is completely divisible by B.

> **Input**:
> The input consists of two lines.
> The first line of the input contains a single integer A.
> The second line of the input contains a single integer B.

> **Output**:
> Print the largest integer ≤A which is completely divisible by B, in a separate line.

Constraints
1≤B≤A≤10^9

This is my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

void file_i_o() {
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  cout.tie(NULL);
  #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("Input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("Output.txt","w",stdout);
  #endif
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
  file_i_o();
  //write your code here
  ll A,B;
  cin>>A>>B;
  ll q = A/B;
  ll n1 = B*q;
  ll n2 = 0;
  if(A*B > 0) {
    n2 = B*(q+1);
  } else {
    n2 = B*(q-1);
  }
  if(abs(A-n1) < abs(A-n2)) {
    if(n1<=A) {
      cout<<n1;
    } 
  } else {
    if(n2<=A) {
      cout<<n2;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with some sample inputs to see if you get the correct result?

Comment: Yes, I checked for positive and negative numbers also

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating the problem. I just looked at the problem. It doesn't need to be that complicated.

This is my solution(AC):

```
void solve(){
    int a, b;
    read(a, b);
    cout << a / b * b << endl;
}
```

---

If you insist on finding out the problem, I can only say that `A * B > 0` is always true, there is no need to judge, maybe it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you are writing so much of code to solve something which can be done in two lines of code.

**Here's the Solution**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long int
using namespace std;

void file_i_o() {
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
  cin.tie(NULL);
  cout.tie(NULL);
  #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("Input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("Output.txt","w",stdout);
  #endif
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
  file_i_o();
  ll A,B;
  cin>>A>>B;
  ll ans = B*(A/B);
  cout << ans;
  return 0;
}
```

I have run this code on codechef and it works.

See this [solution](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/46991837)

Edit- If you are satisfied with my answer please mark it.

Comment: I saw this at geeks for geeks.   
         https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-closest-n-divisible-m/

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please mark my answer as accepted. I dont have any reputation so I can't even vote or comment on others.